# Simple HTML layout engine?

Tags: html, c

I need a HTML layout engine that supports the following:

- rfc2070 HTML 2
- MathML
- Image formats pulgable using a custom plugin format
- Drawing and hyper-link clicking independent of windowing system
- C interface

The purpose is to display program documentation in a nice browsable format. Therefore I do not need any CSS formating support or JavaScript. Does anyone know a good starting point. Gecko seems to be much. Should I try to build a custom one?

Answer (score 2):

> Should I try to build a custom one?

No, absolutely you shouldn't try to build a custom one! There are enough HTML rendering engines out there and you do not need to reinvent the wheel again (even if I suppose it could be pretty funny).

Do you have a target operating system? If you're on Windows you can use Microsoft's [Web Browser Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752040%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to display your pages.

If you're under Linux you have even more options. AFAIK Konqueror can be used for this (and do not forget you can use one of the tons of widget libraries for HTML UI). Take a look to [this list](http://lzone.de/Linux+HTML+Rendering+Widgets) just as starting point.

> The purpose is to display program documentation in a nice browsable format.

Side question: can't you simply show your documentation inside user's default browser? It's pretty common for many programs to provide even on-line documentation inside the browser.

Comment: Drawing and hyper-link clicking independent of windowing system implies that the target not only is cross-platform, but it should not depend on any toolkit. Otherwise it would not fit in the software architecture.

Answer on side question: I could go that way, but I want client search features in a database (sqlite) that is used to generate interface files as well as documentation.

Comment: @user877329 I understand but if you depend on a database (cross-platform) why you can't depend on a library (cross-platform)?

Comment: The GUI and everything else is implemented using system specific backends. On windows, the GUI driver makes direct calls into user32.dll, on Linux it calls GTK or whatever the user wants.

Comment: @user877329 well, so help viewer will be abstracted too and implemented with system specific backend (Microsoft Web Browser Control on Windows and libkhtml on Linux). Ok, just an idea...

Comment: It would be nice if it were possible to method look-up by return type. How do I create or get a Window reference? Well: "Select name form functions where return_type=\"Window*\"" gives you the answer. A plain HTML view cannot do that without dump each such query result, or can it?

Comment: Also MSHTML lacks MathML which is considered as a key feature.

Comment: @user877329 there are many free extensions to add MathML support to MSHTHML (in this case they're called [_Behaviors_](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741312(v=vs.85).aspx).